# Perform Query Using Columns of Table as Arguments

Tags: sql-server, arguments

I need to perform different queries with different arguments. These arguments are arranged in the table T2 below. Everyday these arguments change so the table T2 change and the result of the query I want to do will change. The query is simple but I dont know how to perform  using the columns of T2 as arguments...

```
-----Table T2----

ID  Country   FilterExpression
----------- ------- ------ ----- -----
1   Argentina  'Filter01'
2   Brazil     'Filter02'
3   USA        'Filter03'
4   UK         'Filter04'
5   France     'Filter05'
6   Mexico     'Filter06'
...
100 Canada     'Filter100'
```

The query I need to perform:

```
SELECT Element,Value 
FROM ArchTot
WHERE Country = [Column Country of T2]
AND FilterExpr = [Column FilterExpression of T2]
```

Once I have a Table of arguments of 100 rows, the result of my query must have the same 100 rows.

Somebody can help me to build this query?

Comment: Will FilterExpression contain column names or scalar values?

Answer (score 0):

Try to be more specific so I can understand what you need to do.. Why you need to retrieve 100 for 100? And when The table data changes what happens to The old data... You need to query new data or The data before it changes?

Answer (score 0):

Everyday the table of arguments change so I have to perform the query to update the Result. Once I Have 100 arguments I'll have 100 results:

**`Result of query from Tables Archtot or Archtot2`**

```
Country   FilterExpr   Value
----------- ------- ------ ----- -----
Argentina  'Filter01'  100.82
Brazil     'Filter02'  102.87
USA        'Filter03'  82.7
UK         'Filter04'  106.8
France     'Filter05'  110.7
Mexico     'Filter06'  79.9
...
Canada     'Filter100' 102.04
```

I Tried the following, It works...

```
SELECT A.Element,A.Value 
FROM ArchTot A, T2 B
WHERE A.Country = B.Country
AND A.FilterExpr = B.FilterExpression
```

The problem now is that I Cant perform a INNER JOIN Statement once I have inserted the Table T2 in the FROM clause, it gives timeout. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM
(

    (SELECT A.Element As Element,A.Value As Value, A.Country As Country
    FROM ArchTot A, T2 B
    WHERE A.Country = B.Country
    AND A.FilterExpr = B.FilterExpression)T1

INNER JOIN

    (SELECT C.Element As Element,C.Value As Value, C.Country As Country
    FROM ArchTot2 C, T2 D
    WHERE C.Country = D.Country
    AND C.FilterExpr = D.FilterExpression)T2
    ON T1.Country=T2.Country
)
```

Is the query I Built OK? Any Ideas why I Cant Perform the INNER JOIN?